# Company asks for a scanned copy of my passport

Tags: visa

A while ago I was offered a position by a foreign company in Europe, and they are willing to sponsor my work visa. I checked on the internet, finding that company is backed by a well-known non profit organization, and their news appears on AP as well. Also I checked their phone, address (not from their website) which looks correct. Now they are asking me to give them a copy of my passport for paper work like contract, etc. So this raises several questions because I don't have such experience.

- Is it normal a company to ask for a copy of passport?
- If (the question above is) true, what can I do to protect my privacy (because they want me to send through email)? The only information I find out so far is [1]; however it's more related to travel. Is any information I can safely removed (because they need the entire passport including blank pages)?
- In addition to personal information, etc., anything I may also need to pay attention to or check beforehand?

I appreciate any advice. Thank you very much.

[1]. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39072/how-to-best-respond-to-a-request-to-send-a-passport-scan-by-unsecured-email

Comment: Not sure where you are, but here in the States it's required for the employer to have copies of state issued ID and social security number. If you've got an offer (not just verbal) it's probably just normal onboarding process.

Comment: Some email services automatically encrypt emails due to the way they're being sent. Ex check out gmail: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7039474?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=0. Also just note that there's no way to protect your passport from being abused once it gets to its destination securely.

Comment: Most companies not working directly on cybersecurity stuff are remarkably cavalier about it. I've had the travel agency we use ask me to send them my credit card details by email, which is very much not going to happen.

Comment: @Raystafarian Everyone that's hired has to fill out an I-9 which is intended to prove legal status to work in the United States. Fines for not doing so are hefty. https://www.uscis.gov/i-9-central

Comment: @Raystafarian I didn't say they're required to retain them. I said "have" by which I meant that they're required to fill out the I-9. They are PERMITTED to keep copies but are not required to. In the 30 years since I-9 has been required, every single employer I've had has made copies. In every single case where I've viewed my personnel file, they had retained copies of my SSN and ID long after the I-9 had been filled. They're allowed to retain that information, as such it's standard to provide it.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep I have no argument with any of that, I was just thrown by the language. Thanks

Comment: @ChristopherEstep Just as a side note: In Germany it is widely considered illegal to use a "Personalausweis" (national ID) in any way not explicitly specified in the relevant law. It may be used to prove one's identity to arbitrary third parties, but that means they can look at it, not copy it or keep a copy...

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek it's not considered illegal, it **is** forbidden to give third parties access to your _Personalausweis_. That includes using it as a deposit at the gym, giving a copy or scan to your landlord or to a hotel (also in different countries). You are not even allowed to take a picture of it. Some exceptions include the police and border police, notaries to identify you and banks according to [GwG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/gwg_2008/inhalts_bersicht.html). See [PAuswG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/pauswg/BJNR134610009.html) for more info. It doesn't include passports.

Answer (score 3):

In the U.K., your employer must keep proof of your legal basis to work in the U.K.

Likewise if they are sponsoring a work visa for you, they will have to submit a copy of your passport as part of that process.

In terms of privacy, a copy of your passport will contain your photo, nationality, date of birth and your passport number.

Whilst someone could use these details to pretend to be you online, your exposure in sending the email is probably small if you are sending it from your own computer / phone.

The HR department in a large European company will keep it confidential, and will have systems in place to ensure only appropriate staff have access to it.

If you want to have added reassurance contact the Data protection / information commissioner for the country and verify that the company has registered as a data processor, and see if they have a history of data protection complaints registered against them.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are from, which country you want to relocate to and what kind of visa you are going to need, the company might need the passport for various things.

The reasons I have encountered myself when helping relocate non-EU foreigners via a [§19a AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__19a.html) (blue card) visa to Germany were:

- an invitation letter for the embassy that you apply at for the visa needs to include your passport details
- the foreigner's office approving the visa on their end before it is issued wants a copy up front (e.g. because a blue card *Aufenthaltstitel* is directly tied to your passport and has your passport number on it)
- the travel agency or their HR needs your passport details (and those of your family coming with you) to book your flight if the company pays for your relocation
- your name is very hard for them to spell and they want to make sure they get it right in the contract and on official document for embassies or the local foreigner's office

In addition, they might also want to verify on their end that you are eligible for the type of visa they want to help you to get so you can actually work for them.